# type 'future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'function'

Tags: flutter, future

when i run my app in debug mode it shows me the error "type 'future' is not a subtype of type 'function'" all over the screen and also in the debug console. Can someone help me? I imagine it's a problem with async functions "reset","rateoGet" and "rateoSave" but i can't find any solution. 
P.S. I've deleted part of the code because it was useless for this question.

```
int plus;
int min;
int per;
int div;
double val; 
int gameswon =0;
int moves;
static int mosse=15;
String win = "gioca";
int games=0;
double rateo=1;
String mode;
int flag;
var timer=30;


@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    reset();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: 
            MyButton(text: "$per" ,color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent, onTap: (){
                setState(() {
                    val*=per;
                });
                if(widget.mode=="timermode" && flag==0){
                    timerceckresults();
                }else if(widget.mode=="movesmode"){
                    checkResult();
                }
            },

            MyBottomButton(text: "Reset",color: Colors.indigo,width:160, onTap: reset()),

    ),
}
checkResult() {
    if(val == 101) {
        print("hai vinto");
        win="Hai Vinto";
        setState(() {});
        gameswon++;
        Timer(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
            reset();
    });
    } else {
        print("ci sei quasi");
        moves++;
        mosse--;
        win="$mosse moves left";
        setState(() {});
        if(moves>14){
            print("hai perso coglione");
            win="Hai Perso Coglione";
            setState(() {});
            Timer(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
                reset();
            });
        }
    }
}
timerceckresults(){
    flag=1;
    timer = 30;
    Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (t){
        timer--;
        setState(() {
            win = "${timer.toString()}seconds left";
        });
    if(val==101){
        timer=0;
    }
    if(timer == 0) {
        t.cancel();
        if(val == 101) {
            win="Hai Vinto";
            setState(() {});
            gameswon++;
            Timer(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
                reset();
            });
        } else {
            win="Hai Perso Coglione";
            setState(() {});
            Timer(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
                reset();
            });
        }
    }
});
static int randNum(x,y) {
    var rng = new Random();
    return rng.nextInt(y-x)+x;
}
reset() async{
    timer=1;
    plus = randNum(4, 9);
    min = randNum(5, 19);
    per = randNum(3, 9);
    div = randNum(2, 5);
    val = randNum(2, 11).toDouble();
    moves = 0;
    mosse=15;
    if(widget.mode=="timermode"){
        win="start playing";
    }else{
        win="$mosse moves left";
    }
    await rateoSave();
    await rateoGet();
    games++;
    rateo=gameswon/(games-1);
    await rateoSave();
    flag=0; 
    setState(() {});
}
rateoSave() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs=await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.setInt("games",games);
    await prefs.setInt("gameswon",gameswon);
}
rateoGet() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs=await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    games=(prefs.getInt("games") ?? 0);
    gameswon=(prefs.getInt("gameswon") ?? 0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await read this before you check the answer will help you alot

```
reset() async{
    timer=1;
    plus = randNum(4, 9);
    min = randNum(5, 19);
    per = randNum(3, 9);
    div = randNum(2, 5);
    val = randNum(2, 11).toDouble();
    moves = 0;
    mosse=15;
    if(widget.mode=="timermode"){
        win="start playing";
    }else{
        win="$mosse moves left";
    }
    await rateoSave();
    await rateoGet();
    games++;
    rateo=gameswon/(games-1);
    await rateoSave();
    flag=0; 
    setState(() {});
}
Future<bool> rateoSave() {
    SharedPreferences prefs= SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setInt("games",games);
    prefs.setInt("gameswon",gameswon);
return true;
}

Future<bool> rateoGet() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs= SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await  games=(prefs.getInt("games") ?? 0);
    await  gameswon=(prefs.getInt("gameswon") ?? 0);
    return true;
  }
```

Comment: it give me like errors "sharedpreferences.getinstance()" and at "true"..

Comment: i edited it again my answer have a look at last function

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to get a variable from a method that returns a future. you need to add await just before you make the call to that function.

can you tell us in which line this error occurs ?

Comment: but if i add 'await' before the call of that function from another function i need to turn also that "primitive" function to an async function, right?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by primitive. but my guess is you want to say that you have to await for the function in which you call this function . the answer is no. you only have to turn the function in which you call the other function into async. could you paste the entire error for us to see what is really going on ?

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing to keep in mind is that if **anything** in your call-chain returns a Future, **everything** above it must deal with futures, either by returning the future itself (if no processing must be done), or `await`'ing and dealing with the returned value (but you'll still be returning a future).